# Replace customer account page

Tags: url-rewrite, customer-account

I want to completely replace the customer account page architecture to be a single page with a bunch of tabs.

Rather than remove/update a bunch of blocks within the existing page, I thought it would be easier and instructive to create a new module and layout.

I followed [Alan Storm's awesome tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/magento_create_customer_page), such that I have an account page for

mycompany.com/mycompany_customaccount/index/index

However, how would I get this to be the default mycompany.com/customer/account page?

Otherwise, I tried

```
<customer_account_index>
    <update handle="customer_account" />

    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>mycompany/custom_account_page.phtml</template>
        </action>           
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

To no avail.

What's the best solution here?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options here.
A first would be the easiest, since you have mycompany.com/mycompany_customaccount/index/index working you could rewrite customer/account/index to it.

A second one would be makeing the page one column and replacing the dashboard, removing left is also an option there. If there are no tabs, your page and your own tabs are the only options.